# Double whitespace in some badges tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tooltips

Whenever there's `Reviewer` badge being displayed its tooltip contains a double whitespace between the description sentences. Same for `Custodian` and `Steward`.

[image: double whitespace]

This looks like a bug.

Comment: Maybe not a bug, but that's definitely inconsistent. _Some_ people think that's the right way of separating two sentences.

Comment: *Devil's advocate mode:* In English, sentences may end with two spaces. [Traditionally, two spaces could distinguish from a mid-sentence abbreviation or initials, as in, "He was faster than I. P. Jones was next."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing) Also, you have good eyes.

Comment: But then you get stuff like this: http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/technology/2011/01/space_invaders.html

Comment: My OCD sense is tingling.

Comment: Oh, you think you have OCD when something is askew? http://www.cracked.com/blog/4-things-no-one-tells-you-about-having-ocd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It<strike>'s</strike> was off in the normal content  too!!!1

[image: source]

Fixed as soon as you see builds `2013.11.8.1620` on meta and `2013.11.8.1141` on sites roll out

Comment: Sure it was off in the actual content and this is exactly why it was rendered that way.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. Is this some meme?

Comment: @sharptooth: How does that image make you feel?

Comment: I'm kind of still alive and not breaking stuff yet.

Comment: Congratulations!